# Trying to make bone monster, not sure how to go about it

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to model a monster made out of bones but m not sure how to really go about doing it. I have a base object i want to wrap all the bones around, and i tried geometry nodes but couldn't really get the result i want. I'm somewhat new to blender and very new to geometry nodes, so if anyone has any advice about the geometry nodes or another approach Id be happy to hear.

Base model I'm trying to wrap bones around to make it look like its made of bones.
[image: Base model I'm trying to wrap bones around to make it look like its made of bones.]

This is what I'm trying to do.
[image: This is what I'm trying to do.]

Comment: Sure you can get some automated bone distribution with something like _Geometry Nodes_. But the example you show is an artistic approach, maybe you could get away with some random placing of bones, but most of them you have to deliberately place manually in certain places where they look good.